# Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: сессия, php

В общем, проблема в следующем:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\ses\login.php:1) in Z:\home\localhost\www\ses\login.php on line 16

Читал форумы, там пишут что проблема в кодировке. Я везде установил UTF-8 без BOM (в Notepad++), но проблема осталась:

**form.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="login.php">

        <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></p>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Let me in" /></p>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
// Проверить корректность username и password
if ($_POST["username"] == "php" && $_POST["password"] == "php") {
    // Если корректны, устанавливаем значение сессии в YES
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["Login"] = "YES";
    echo "<h1>Вы зашли корректно</h1>";
    echo "<p><a href='document.php'>Ссылка на защищённый файл</a><p/>";
} else {
    // Если некорректны, устанавливаем сессию в NO
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["Login"] = "NO";
    echo "<h1>Вы зашли НЕкорректно </h1>";
    echo "<p><a href='document.php'>Ссылка на защищённый файл</a><p/>"; 
}
```

Comment: проблема решилась,но теперь как то ееё закрывать надо будет.Например если пользователь выходит из ЛЧ.Команда session_destroy не спасет ?

Comment: В файле login.php перед <?php есть пробелы?

Comment: Убрал пробелы! не помогло.Проблема в сессии.В кодировке вопрос решен

Comment: Так все-таки пробелы были. Проблема, как вы выразились, не в сессии - сессия не может быть запущена, потому что есть некий `output` в строке 1 файла `login.php`. Проще сейчас сделать следующее: создайте файл в ноутпаде, скопируйте код туда, сохраните как `login.php` и перезапишите. Если уже экстремально, то "рассмотрите" свой оригинальный `login.php` в редакторе, который отображает т.н. `non-printable characters`. Или просмотрите его в `HEX-Viewer` - это поможет увидеть, что стоит перед символом `<`. Я уверен, что там что-то будет.

Comment: исправьте, пожалуйста выражение "В общем" )

Answer (score 1):

> Читал форумы.Там пишут что проблема в кодировке.

nope

Хедеры, в т.ч. сессия должны выводиться до тела страницы. Тело страницы начинается как минимум здесь

```
<html> <head> <title>Login</title>
```

А хедеры посылаются здесь:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: @Etki, или использовать буферизацию

Comment: Приведенные выше строчки расположены в разных файлах.

Comment: @DarkGenius, это не имеет вообще никакой разницы, пушо наличие ошибки определяется порядком вывода, а в каких файлах производится этот вывод - PHP уже не волнует.

Comment: @Etki, у каждого файла свой вывод, если только один не включается в другой. Ты считаешь, что при выполнении login.php возникает ошибка, потому что в form.php есть вывод? Но login.php это уже ответ на другой HTTP-запрос, и не важно, что там выводилось в form.php

Comment: @DarkGenius, хм, тогда, возможно, это пробелы перед `<?php`. В любом случае этот вывод где-то там есть.

Answer (score 1):

Если сессии нужны на каждой странице, то открываем php.ini и находим там `session.auto_start`.

Включаем его.

`session.auto_start = 1`

Answer (score 1):

В коде страницы `login.php` уберите все пробелы перед `<?php`.

**Обновление**

Так все-таки пробелы были. Проблема, как вы выразились, не в сессии - сессия не может быть запущена, потому что есть некий `output` в строке 1 файла `login.php`. Проще сейчас сделать следующее: создайте файл в ноутпаде, скопируйте код туда, сохраните как `login.php` и перезапишите. Если уже экстремально, то "рассмотрите" свой оригинальный `login.php` в редакторе, который отображает т.н. `non-printable characters`. Или просмотрите его в `HEX-Viewer` - это поможет увидеть, что стоит перед символом `<`. Я уверен, что там что-то будет.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

> // Если корректны, устанавливаем
> значение сессии в YES
> session_start();

Если в файле нужна сессия, то ее необходимо объявить в самом начале файла и только потом весь остальной код.
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html> 
  <head> 
.......

**2.**
Для остановки сессии команда  session_stop();

Comment: И еще session_start(); мало того что в начале документа только, дак еще и 1 раз и не более.

Answer (score 0):

Ну да! Сначала session_start() а потом все остальное. У тебя же сначала отправляются данные (так ты проверяешь массив пост) то он у тебя не пустой, данные через форму отправлены. А потом уже стартуешь сессию. Отсюда и ошибка. Сначала стартуй сессию, а потом уже проверяй массив $_POST

Comment: Но ведь проверка $_POST - это проверка полученного HTTP-запроса, во время проверки данные по идее не отправляются в ответе клиенту.